# How to manipulate clipboard string using before pasting it?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write two VBA codes.

The first one is to add parentheses around the quotes text and remove line breaks and paragraph breaks.

- The copied text always has a line break and then paragraph break near the end.
  I would like to remove this, add in two double spaced, and put parentheses at the start of the text and right before where the line break was, and add a period at the end and then paste it.
- An example would be:

> A mandamus is the proper remedy[line break][paragraph break] Marburg v. Madison, 5 U.S. 137, 139 (1803)

- Pasted To:

> "A mandamus is the proper remedy." Marburg v. Madison, 5 U.S. 137, 139 (1803).

My second code would do the same thing, but flip it and add parentheses as well.

- The finished product would like like:

> Marburg v. Madison, 5 U.S. 137, 139 (1803) ("A mandamus is the proper remedy.").

How do I manipulate a string on the clipboard like this.

```vb
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As range
Set Rng = Selection.range
Rng.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis)
With Rng
    .InsertBefore Chr(147)
    .MoveStartUntil Chr(11), wdForward
    .End = .Start + 2
    .Text = Chr(148) & "  "
End With
Selection.MoveStartUntil ")", wdForward
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For the Demoflipped, I tried

```vb
Rng.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis)
```

Comment: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/ManipulateClipboard.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub DemoStraight()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Rng
  .Paste
  .Text = Chr(34) & Replace(.Text, Chr(11) & vbCr, Chr(34) & ". ")
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and:

```
Sub DemoFlipped()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, StrTmp As String
Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Rng
  .Paste
  StrTmp = Replace(.Text, Chr(11), "")
  .Text = Split(StrTmp, vbCr)(1) & " (" & Chr(34) & Split(StrTmp, vbCr)(0) & Chr(34) & ".)"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Format retention requires a different approach. For example:

```
Sub DemoStraight()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Rng
  .Paste
  .InsertBefore Chr(34)
  .MoveStartUntil Chr(11), wdForward
  .End = .Start + 2
  .Text = Chr(34) & ". "
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and:

```
Sub DemoFlipped()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngA As Range, RngB As Range, StrTmp As String
Set RngA = Selection.Range
With RngA
  .Paste
  Do While .Characters.Last Like "[ " & Chr(11) & vbCr & "]"
    .End = .End - 1
  Loop
  .InsertBefore " (" & Chr(34)
  Set RngB = .Duplicate
  With RngB
    .MoveStartUntil Chr(11), wdForward
    .End = .Start + 2
    .Text = Chr(34) & ".) "
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .End = RngA.End
  End With
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  .FormattedText = RngB.FormattedText
  RngB.Text = vbNullString
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That is so close to what I needed. The only problem is it puts the period inside the quote instead of at the end of the entire phrase. When I try to modofy the code to put "." at the end by bringing it out of the replace text part and adding it after it puts it at the front for some reason. It also causes issue when I tried to replace the .paste with a paste to merge formatting.

Comment: «The only problem is it puts the period inside the quote instead of at the end of the entire phrase.» Which is how you depicted the desired outcome. I have edited the code. An entirely different approach is required to preserve to original's formatting. See revised answer.

Comment: I change the code to paste using merge formatting, it worked for the first but not the second code.  I modify it so the cursor goes to the end of the pasted text, like with normal paste.  I got it close, but not quite working.  Code in original question.